# Xcode Warnings: What is "Unused Labels"

Tags: xcode, warnings, build-settings

In Xcode if you go to project build settings, under warnings there is entry for "Unused labels". What is meant by the term "Labels"?

I understand what is meant by unused (for example, "unused variable")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **label** can be used in C (and therefore Objective-C) to mark a point in your code and is typically seen with **goto**.  (Using goto is often considered not best practice).

If you omitted the line with **goto** below, the compiler can warn you if you set the *unused labels warning*.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        goto myLabel
        NSLog(@"I won't print");

myLabel:
        NSLog(@"I will print");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks :)